# Error while retrieving values from local database

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In this function:

```
public IList<foods> GetFoods()
{
    IList<foods> myFoods = null;

    using (var db = new FoodsContext(ConnectionString))
    {
        var query = from e in db.MyFoods
                    select e;

        myFoods = query.ToList();

        return myFoods;
    }
}
```

I get an error on:

```
myFoods = query.ToList();
```

the error says:

> InvalidCastException was unhandled

But I can get the values of a certain column, i.e: when I write:

```
var query = from e in db.MyFoods
    select e.calorie;
```

I get calorie column correctly. So where can be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of your `foods` class and the exception's callstack?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I believe the result of your linq query cannot be directly cast to foods class object collection. Try the below code

```
public IList<foods> GetFoods()
    {
        IList<foods> myFoods = null;

        using (var db = new FoodsContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            var query = from e in db.MyFoods
                        select new foods
                        {
                            calorie = e.calorie,

                            // Map other properties of foods object here

                        };

            myFoods = query.ToList();

            return myFoods;
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you get error with details

Comment: The same thing with the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are using Linq2SQL and `db.MyFoods` means your table name is `MyFood`. So when you try for `query.ToList();` it will return you the `List<MyFood>` and your trying to convert from `List<MyFood>` to `IList<foods>` which leads to `InvalidCastException`.

Try this,

```
public IList<foods> GetFoods()
{
    using (var db = new FoodsContext(ConnectionString))
    {
        return db.Employees.Select(e => new foods 
                                         { 
                                           calorie = e.calorie,

                                           // Map other properties of foods object here
                                         }).ToList<foods>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Actually, no I get the error: "Explicit construction of entity type 'test.foods' in query is not allowed."